# Cython Examples Failing

Tags: python, cython

I tried to run the examples in page:

http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html#the-basics-of-cython

on Windows 10 using Visual studio 2017 and python 3.53 x64.

Compilation was OK.  But when I try to import the generated pyd (dll) into Python 3.53 (x64), I get an error.

The generated pyd file and the rest of the files are all in the same folder.

Has any one managed to run successfully those 3 examples in the above link under Python 3.5 with Visual Studio 2017 ?

Comment: Copy the error (the whole traceback) and paste it into your question; without knowing what error you got, it's hard to debug the error.

Comment: import helloworld.cp35-win_amd64
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Please put that into your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just that you're not importing the modules correctly.

Just as you use `import spam`, not `import spam.py`, for a Python module, you use `import spam`, not `import spam.cp35-win_amd64` for an extension module.

Notice that the example you linked to does it like that:

```
>>> import helloworld
Hello World
```

If you're wondering why you got exactly the error you did: the `-` character isn't part of a name, it's an arithmetic operator. So you were telling it you want to import the module `cp35 - win_amd64` from the package `spam`, and that confused the parser, so it gave you a `SyntaxError`.

---

Since you asked about your particular toolset: Yes, those all work together. In fact, as documented [on the wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers), all Python 3.5 installers from python.org are built with Visual C++ 14.0, which is the compiler that comes with Visual Studio 2017, and come with a `distutils` that can automatically detect and use it. (If you have an old version of `setuptools`—type `pip show setuptools` to see if the version number is at least 34.4.0—it can cause problems, but those problems prevent Cython packages from compiling at all.)

Comment: Thanks.  You are right.  The generated pyd file "helloworld.cp35-win_amd64.pyd"  should be kept unchanged in the same folder.  But the import should say    import helloworld     only